# Text not showing in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was working on this site.Please check the link http://mrsinghcafe.com/real/
It has a slider on home page with text.In small resolutions the slider appears but without Text
I want text also to appear on small resolutions.

I tried adding the following to my css

```
#slidecaption
{
display:block;
}
.slide_text
 {
display:block;
}
```

but didn't help.Can some one please help me .Thanks.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `display:none;` of the `#div1content` is responsible here:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

  #div1content{ display:none;}

}
```

Remove it and position the text how you like it.

Comment: thatnks that gave me a way to the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

found this in your CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 #slidecaption {
    ...
 }
 .slide_text {
    display: none;
 }
 #slidecaption h2 {
    ...
 }
}
```

`.slide_text` is `display: none`, and after this rule, no rule to set it to block again.

in slider_text_n_desription.css, you will find above rule. overrule it a bit down by adding `display: block`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
 .slide_text {
    bottom: 120px;
    font-family: 'Eurostile-Normal';
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
 }
}
```

Comment: can you please give me more detail please

Answer (score -3):

```
#slidecaption
{
    display:block;
}
.slide_text
{
   display:block;
}
```

use semicolones

Comment: then open console, inspect element, and look at wich styles are making trouble, if they are still display:none probably other styles have more prioritized selectors. If no look at overlows

Comment: a bit confused with the css . Please help